# Android change ListView dimension by number item array

Tags: android, listview

i would like to change the height of my list view respect a numebr of items array
this is my layout:`

```
 <RelativeLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="250dp"
            android:id="@+id/lyft_id">
            <ListView
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="250dp"
                android:id="@+id/lista1"
                android:divider="@null"
                android:dividerHeight="0dp"></ListView>

        </RelativeLayout>
```

and this my code to populate list:

```
ListAdapter adapter = new SimpleAdapter(
                Tariffe.this, lyftList,
                R.layout.raw_tariffe, new String[]{"name_1", "costo_1"}, new int[]{R.id.tipo, R.id.costo});


        int numberOfitems = adapter.getCount();
        lv1.setAdapter(adapter);
```

How i can change the height listview by numeber items of array?
Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can set the height of the `ListView` through `setLayoutParams`. For example:

```
lv1.setLayoutParams(new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(new_width, new_height));
```

Hope it helps!